# What is the best practice for creating a View from a Single Lookup Table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, view, lookup, sql-server-2019

I have a fairly large table mostly consisting of lookup id's referencing a single lookup table. I understand that this is generally not considered best practice, but unfortunately that aspect is outside of my control.

What I wish to do is create a View that converts the lookup id's into their corresponding descriptions (25-30 lookup columns in this particular table). My options, from what I've read, seem to be the following. My question is which of these (or any other method I'm not thinking of) would provide the best combination of of performance, readability and extensibility.

1. Simply creating a Left JOIN for each column with a separate table alias.
2. Inline Table-Valued Function using a subquery to return the desired lookup
3. Inline Scalar-Valued Function using the new 2019 SQL Server optimizations for Scalar UDF's.

1 seems to be the most straightforward, but would be cumbersome to maintain and read, and wouldn't be able to translate to other tables I need this functionality for.

2 seems to be more extensible but not by much and I'm not sure how much performance would suffer compared to #1.

3 is my preference, as it's extremely extensible and makes the view much more readable. However I understand this is a new addition to MSSQL so I'm doubly concerned of potential performance issues vs 1.

Does anyone have any input/advice on this particular approach?

EDIT: Here's an example that highlights the potential burden of using straight joins. This particular view required me to incorporate a combination of short codes and descriptions into one. I think an inline UDF would make this much more readable and flexible, but before I go through all the work of converting it, I just wanted to get a feel of if it would even be a practical option...

```
SELECT dbo.Clients.client_id, dbo.Clients.ssn, dbo.ClientEpisode.admission_date, dbo.Clients.rin, ISNULL(admission_type.lookup_code, admit_type.lookup_code) 
                     AS admission_type, dbo.ClientEpisode.initial_contact_date, dbo.ClientEpisode.assessment_date, dbo.Clients.first_name, dbo.Clients.last_name, 
                     dbo.Clients.middle_initial, dbo.Clients.dob, dbo.Clients.address_1 + ' ' + ISNULL(dbo.Clients.address_2, '') AS address, dbo.Clients.city, dbo.Clients.state, 
                     dbo.Clients.zip_code, geocode.lookup_code AS geocode, race.lookup_code + ' - ' + race.lookup_desc AS race, 
                     hispanic_origin.lookup_code + ' - ' + hispanic_origin.lookup_desc AS hispanic_origin, dbo.Clients.gender, dbo.Clients.veteran_status, 
                     marital_status.lookup_code + ' - ' + marital_status.lookup_desc AS marital_status, dbo.Clients.family_size, dbo.Clients.num_receiving_child_support, 
                     dbo.Clients.num_of_children, dbo.Clients.num_removed_from_custody, pregnant.lookup_code + ' - ' + pregnant.lookup_desc AS pregnant, 
                     livingarrange.lookup_code + ' - ' + livingarrange.lookup_desc AS livingarrange, paysource.lookup_code + ' - ' + paysource.lookup_desc AS paysource, 
                     medicaidmco.lookup_code + ' - ' + medicaidmco.lookup_desc AS medicaidmco, empstatus.lookup_code + ' - ' + empstatus.lookup_desc AS empstatus, 
                     unemployment.lookup_code + ' - ' + unemployment.lookup_desc AS unemployment, schooljob.lookup_code + ' - ' + schooljob.lookup_desc AS schooljob, 
                     dbo.Clients.highest_grade_completed AS education, dbo.Clients.annual_income, income_source.lookup_code + ' - ' + income_source.lookup_desc AS income_source,
                      hearing_status.lookup_code + ' - ' + hearing_status.lookup_desc AS hearing_status, 
                     family_income_override.lookup_code + ' - ' + family_income_override.lookup_desc AS family_income_override, 
                     preferred_language.lookup_code + ' - ' + preferred_language.lookup_desc AS preferred_language, dbo.Clients.english_speaking, 
                     priorepisodes.lookup_code + ' - ' + priorepisodes.lookup_desc AS prior_treatment_episodes, 
                     referral_source.lookup_code + ' - ' + referral_source.lookup_desc AS referral_source, referral_office.lookup_code + ' - ' + referral_office.lookup_desc AS referral_office,
                      dbo.ClientEpisode.dcfs_involvement, dbo.ClientEpisode.misa_involvement, dbo.ClientAdmissionData.numarrests, dbo.ClientAdmissionData.numgroups, 
                     attendgroups.lookup_code AS attendgroups, dbo.Clients.support_in_recovery, problemarea.lookup_code + ' - ' + problemarea.lookup_desc AS problemarea, 
                     primdrug.lookup_code + ' - ' + primdrug.lookup_desc AS primdrug, primdrugfreq.lookup_code + ' - ' + primdrugfreq.lookup_desc AS primdrugfreq, 
                     primdrugrout.lookup_code + ' - ' + primdrugrout.lookup_desc AS primdrugrout, primdrugsevr.lookup_code + ' - ' + primdrugsevr.lookup_desc AS primdrugsevr, 
                     dbo.ClientAdmissionData.primdrugage, secdrug.lookup_code + ' - ' + secdrug.lookup_desc AS secdrug, 
                     secdrugfreq.lookup_code + ' - ' + secdrugfreq.lookup_desc AS secdrugfreq, secdrugrout.lookup_code + ' - ' + secdrugrout.lookup_desc AS secdrugrout, 
                     secdrugsevr.lookup_code + ' - ' + secdrugsevr.lookup_desc AS secdrugsevr, dbo.ClientAdmissionData.secdrugage, 
                     tertdrug.lookup_code + ' - ' + tertdrug.lookup_desc AS tertdrug, tertdrugfreq.lookup_code + ' - ' + tertdrugfreq.lookup_desc AS tertdrugfreq, 
                     tertdrugrout.lookup_code + ' - ' + tertdrugrout.lookup_desc AS tertdrugrout, tertdrugsevr.lookup_code + ' - ' + tertdrugsevr.lookup_desc AS tertdrugsevr, 
                     dbo.ClientAdmissionData.tertdrugage, dbo.ClientAdmissionData.currentlevel, dbo.ClientAdmissionData.leveldate, dbo.ClientAdmissionData.formtype, 
                     dbo.ClientAdmissionData.date_entered, dbo.ClientAdmissionData.emp_name FROM dbo.ClientEpisode INNER JOIN
                     dbo.ClientAdmissionData ON dbo.ClientEpisode.episode_id = dbo.ClientAdmissionData.episode_id INNER JOIN
                     dbo.Clients ON dbo.ClientAdmissionData.client_id = dbo.Clients.client_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                     dbo.LookupDict AS geocode ON dbo.ClientAdmissionData.geocode = geocode.lookup_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                     dbo.LookupDict AS admission_type ON dbo.ClientEpisode.admission_type = admission_type.lookup_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                     dbo.LookupDict AS admit_type ON dbo.ClientAdmissionData.admittype = admit_type.lookup_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                     dbo.LookupDict AS race ON dbo.Clients.race = race.lookup_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                     dbo.LookupDict AS hispanic_origin ON dbo.Clients.hispanic_origin = hispanic_origin.lookup_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                     dbo.LookupDict AS pregnant ON dbo.ClientAdmissionData.pregnant = pregnant.lookup_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                     dbo.LookupDict AS livingarrange ON dbo.ClientAdmissionData.livingarrang = livingarrange.lookup_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                     dbo.LookupDict AS medicaidmco ON dbo.ClientEpisode.medicaid_mco_provider = medicaidmco.lookup_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                     dbo.LookupDict AS paysource ON dbo.ClientEpisode.pay_source = paysource.lookup_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                     dbo.LookupDict AS empstatus ON dbo.ClientAdmissionData.employment = empstatus.lookup_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                     dbo.LookupDict AS unemployment ON dbo.ClientAdmissionData.unemployment = unemployment.lookup_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                     dbo.LookupDict AS schooljob ON dbo.ClientAdmissionData.schooljob = schooljob.lookup_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                     dbo.LookupDict AS family_income_override ON dbo.Clients.family_income_override = family_income_override.lookup_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                     dbo.LookupDict AS income_source ON dbo.Clients.income_source = income_source.lookup_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                     dbo.LookupDict AS preferred_language ON dbo.Clients.preferred_language = preferred_language.lookup_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                     dbo.LookupDict AS hearing_status ON dbo.Clients.hearing_status = hearing_status.lookup_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                     dbo.LookupDict AS referral_source ON dbo.ClientEpisode.referral_source = referral_source.lookup_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                     dbo.LookupDict AS referral_office ON dbo.ClientEpisode.referral_office = referral_office.lookup_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                     dbo.LookupDict AS priorepisodes ON dbo.Clients.prior_treatment_episodes = priorepisodes.lookup_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                     dbo.LookupDict AS problemarea ON dbo.ClientAdmissionData.problemarea = problemarea.lookup_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                     dbo.LookupDict AS primdrug ON dbo.ClientAdmissionData.primdrug = primdrug.lookup_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                     dbo.LookupDict AS primdrugfreq ON dbo.ClientAdmissionData.primdrugfreq = primdrugfreq.lookup_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                     dbo.LookupDict AS primdrugrout ON dbo.ClientAdmissionData.primdrugrout = primdrugrout.lookup_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                     dbo.LookupDict AS primdrugsevr ON dbo.ClientAdmissionData.primdrugsevr = primdrugsevr.lookup_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                     dbo.LookupDict AS secdrug ON dbo.ClientAdmissionData.secdrug = secdrug.lookup_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                     dbo.LookupDict AS secdrugfreq ON dbo.ClientAdmissionData.secdrugfreq = secdrugfreq.lookup_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                     dbo.LookupDict AS secdrugrout ON dbo.ClientAdmissionData.secdrugrout = secdrugrout.lookup_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                     dbo.LookupDict AS secdrugsevr ON dbo.ClientAdmissionData.secdrugsevr = secdrugsevr.lookup_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                     dbo.LookupDict AS tertdrug ON dbo.ClientAdmissionData.tertdrug = tertdrug.lookup_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                     dbo.LookupDict AS tertdrugfreq ON dbo.ClientAdmissionData.tertdrugfreq = tertdrugfreq.lookup_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                     dbo.LookupDict AS tertdrugrout ON dbo.ClientAdmissionData.tertdrugrout = tertdrugrout.lookup_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                     dbo.LookupDict AS tertdrugsevr ON dbo.ClientAdmissionData.tertdrugsevr = tertdrugsevr.lookup_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                     dbo.LookupDict AS marital_status ON dbo.Clients.marital_status = marital_status.lookup_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                     dbo.LookupDict AS attendgroups ON dbo.ClientAdmissionData.attendgroups = attendgroups.lookup_id
```

Comment: what will be the purpose for the view, convenience? will anyone ever need to see descriptions for each of the lookup id's?

Comment: Mostly for reporting purposes. Depending on the request, groupings & column selection could come from any of the lookup columns, so yes they do often need to see descriptions.

Comment: well if a user selects only 2 lookups but you create a view for all, all joins will be evaluated. performance will suffer either way and probably more so with use of functions. maybe generating the proper sql for required columns is a better option if possible.

Comment: I didn't realize that. That's good to know, and unfortunate that I can't simply flatten the data as I need.

Comment: Upon some further reading, it seems that only INNER Joins are evaluated pre-query regardless of column selection. LEFT joins are not binding so don't suffer the same performance hit.

Answer (score 0):

I am clearly missing something because I don't see how a scalar UDF would be more "extensible" -- unless you mean that you can change the data model and not change the view.

I don't see what is cumbersome about using left joins for this purpose, so a view seems like an obvious solution.  If you do use scalar UDF, then computed columns using those UDFs seems like a good approach.

That said, there are two more important considerations.  If performance is an issue, then try out the different approaches (on reasonably-sized data) to see which is best.  Second, what are you most comfortable with?  You will need to write, maintain, document, and test the code.

Comment: Extensible meaning I could modify a single line to alter the lookup return (i.e. if I needed to return a lookup_code instead of a description.

Comment: @DanielThompson . . . That would also be very simple in a view.

Comment: I'll post an example above that highlights my issues with using straight joins. Thanks for the input though!

Comment: Ok example added. With this in mind, is a straightfoward LEFT JOIN still clearly the best option? We are redesigning/migrating tables now which is why I wanted to explore alternatives

Comment: I don't see any issue with just using the straightforward LEFT JOIN.  For a table like you're describing, the code will always look a bit of a mess, no matter what you do.  If I had to maintain it, I wouldn't find the view in your example to be burdensome at all.